# Android dbAdapter custom query

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using the Notepad example for my class definition of a DBAdapter.

An example of my table structure:

```
Vehicle -> "_id", "registration", "idmake", "model"
Make -> "_id", "name"
```

At the moment I'm using a query to get the vehicle data and fill a ListView:

```
public Cursor fetchVehicles() {

    return mDb.query("Vehicle", new String[] { "_id", "registration",
            "idmake", "model" }, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

My question is, how can I make a query like this except it returns the corresponding Make name instead of the idmake field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `JOIN` these two tables.

```
String SELECT_NAME = "SELECT M.name FROM Make M INNER JOIN Vehicle V ON M._id = V._id";
cursor.rawQuery(SELECT_NAME, null);
```

Second param in `rawQuery` method takes `where args` so you can do that like this:

```
String ANOTHER_SELECT = "SELECT M.name FROM Make M INNER JOIN Vehicle V ON M._id = V._id WHERE M._id = ?";
cursor.rawQuery(ANOTHER_SELECT, new String[] {String.valueOf(<dataId>)});
```

A little a few about [rawQuery method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html)

Regards

Comment: So i'm glad man, so if it works, accept this for others those one in these days will looking for same thing :-)